# Pass elements with placeholders

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to Ionic and am creating a piece of code that generates options for a select-box.

I have created a json array with data containing country codes and such.

```
{
    "Countries":
              [
                {
                    "Country": "Nederland",
                    "Countrycode": "NL",
                    "Languagecode": "nl-nl"
                },{
                    "Country": "United Kingdom",
                    "Countrycode": "UK",
                    "Languagecode": "gb-en"
                },{
                    "Country": "Deutschland",
                    "Countrycode": "DE",
                    "Languagecode": "de-de"
                }
              ]
}
```

I have created a for loop that creates elements for each country. That code looks like the following:

```
for (let index = 0; index < this.languages.Countries.length; index++) {
      if(this.languages.Countries[index].Languagecode !== undefined || this.languages.Countries[index].Country !== undefined){
        this.countryoptions += "<ion-select-option value="+this.languages.Countries[index].Languagecode+">"+this.languages.Countries[index].Country+"</ion-select-option>";
      }
    }
```

The above works fine, it outputs elements and when I copy and paste the output directly the select-box works fine. But when I use **{{countryoptions}}** it adds "undefined ...OUPUT..." (OUTPUT means the output from the for loop) and then the select-box does not work. I tried removing the "" marks using .replace(); but with no success.

I can give the output of the loop aswell, but my question is already mostly code. So I think I can leave that out. If not let me know :)

**So to recap my question:**

How do I pass my variable through a placeholder {{}} without it adding quotes that break the elements?

Kind regards,
Robbert

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor 

angular provide a good documentation with examples .. check out this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the loop directly in your html template.

```html
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let country of languages?.Countries" [value]="country.Languagecode">
  {{country.Country}}
</ion-select-option>
```

assuming you have got the object `languages` which contains a property called `Countries` which is an array.

**The Observable way**

If you retrieve your value with http, you will get back an `Observable<YourDataType>`. If thats the case,  you should also use angulars build-in `async` pipe.

```html
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let country of (languages$ | async)?.Countries" [value]="country.Languagecode">
```

Comment: That's great!do you like to accept the answer if it was helpful? :)

Comment: Ofcourse! I was pulled away so I wasnt able to do it just yet :)